Como convertir un char en date? sql server
Holas, estoy intentado convertir a Date una columna que es char, la columna "Mes"

he intentando con convert y format, me sale error
select  CIC,  convert(date,Mes) as Mes,saldo from #tblsaldo
  where CIC like '    00034060'

quisiera que el formato se "YY/mm/DD" ejemplo '2022/03/01' es decir agregar el dia y que sea 1

Te falta concatenar el día, porque estas convirtiendo solo año + mes
CONVERT(date,CONCAT(mes, '01')) as Mes

Esto te va a retornar yyyy-MM-dd
Para cambiar por slash, puede usar format
FORMAT(CONVERT(date,CONCAT(mes, '01')),'yyyy/MM/dd') as Mes

Salida : yyyy/MM/dd
